# Solve for $k$ when the equation has equal roots

Tags: quadratics, discriminant

**UPDATE:** *Solved thanks to turkyhundt and jimbo*

The mathematical question is as follows:

> Calculate the value of $k$ for which $2x^2 + 4x - k = 0$ has equal roots.

*My working solves it to equal $-2$, but if we then put this back into the formula this is, of course, impossible. I use the discriminate of the quadratic equation, $b^2-4ac$.*

Comment: Plugging in $-2$ gives you $2x^2+4x+2=0$ or $x^2+2x+1=0$ which does indeed give two equal roots.  So I think you are correct that $k=-2$.  As long as we are clear that the equation has a $-k$

Comment: @turkeyhundt If you put this back into b^2-4ac it equals 32.

Comment: $c=-k$, $k=-2$, so $b^2-4ac=4^2-(4)(2)(-(-2))=4^2-(4)(2)(2)=0$

Comment: @turkeyhundt Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$b^2-4ac=4^2-4(2)(-k)=16+8k=0$ imply $k=-2$

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Another approach:}$
\begin{align}
2x^2 + 4x - k &= 0\\
x^2 +4x-\frac{k}{2}&= 0 \\ 
(x+1)^2-1 &=\frac{k}{2} \\
0 &=\frac{k}{2}+1 \\
k &=-2
\end{align}